# Will this setup create much audio interference for me?

Tags: audio, automotive, cables, interference

I'll be installing a ipod adapter kit in my 2004 honda accord, and on the device that connects to my stereo, it includes stereo outputs - red/white - that i can connect with a stereo to 3.5mm cable to plug in any other device and listen to it through the stereo.

My question is, since I bought a 6ft cable without really thinking, will I get much interference from winding up the cable in bunch to fit it under the stereo? As opposed to just getting a shorter cable.

Here is the cable for reference: [http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Audio-Cable-Splitter-1-Mini/dp/B00004Z5CP/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1323873682&sr=8-5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Z5CP)

This is the interface that I will be installing: [http://www.amazon.com/USA-PA15-HON2-Interface-Select-Factory/dp/B001JT5G4G/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323879039&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JT5G4G)

Wasn't sure how much self-interference from the cable being bunched up together - like in the amazon pic - I would get, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine bunching it all up.  Normally, in a car, interference on the cable is minor compared to other sources of interference-- like the noise the ignition system puts onto the power.

Comment: As a specific example of this, I have a switch in my truck that lets me switch between a Mini Plug, a Zune connector, and then an empty input. The mini plug is about 4 feet longer then the zune cable and all 3 inputs sound to have the same amount of noise on them. I do get a nice whine out of my speakers when I am accelerating though :-(

Answer (score 1):

You will be fine with rolling up the cable. It is ill advised mostly because the voltage can drop and cause problems with audio quality if you pass it through an equalizer with out using a pre-amp. But that is talking about professional sound systems that start to cost in the tens of thousands.

If you get a clicking noise, or feed back from the rev'ing of your engine then you might have a ground loop feedback that can be solved by installing ground loop isolation to the +12 volt of the radio and/or the Amplifier/s

> A Hint: When doing a set up like yours, remember to set the output
>   volume to 100% before micro tuning your amplifiers, this will avoid
>   your friends coming up and pumping the volume up and causing
>   distortion on your speakers, which can lead to permanently damage of
>   the speaker it self. So you will always know you are safe even if your
>   device is pumping 100% volume. These setting do vary from device to
>   device though, so if you plan on using several ones that is when a pre-amp can come in handy.

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick, but...  Professional sound systems can run analog audio signals for more than 300 feet without issues.  The voltage drop on a 6 foot cable is insignificant because the current is tiny.  If an EQ doesn't work right without a preamp then the EQ was designed by an idiot(tm).  The whine you hear that matches when the engine revs has absolutely nothing to do with ground loops and everything to do with noise the ignition system puts on the car's power system-- filter out the noise and you get rid of the whine.